# Examples of geometric structures on real manifold that lead to almost complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, smooth-manifolds

I have a $M^{2n}$ real manifold. I am interested, if there are any well known geometric structures on manifold that lead in some natural manner to almost complex structure on $M.$

I read on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Compatible_triples) about compatible triples and I think one example would be triple $(M,\omega,g)$ consisting of symplectic form $\omega$ and metric tensor $g,$ such that $$g(X,Y)=\omega(X,(i_Y\omega)^\sharp)$$ for all vector fields $X,Y.$ We can define then an almost complex structure $J$ as follows:
$$J(X)=(i_X\omega)^\sharp.$$

I am looking for this type of examples.

Btw. I am aware that there is an almost complex structure derived from complex manifold.

---

Edit. After Jack's comment I added compatibility condition $g(X,Y)=\omega(X,(i_Y\omega)^\sharp).$

---

**Edit.** Almost cosympletic structure from [Olszak's paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kmj/1138036371) looks promising, but it is odd dimensional, so no chance. Maybe someone is familiar with similar structures, but on even dimensional mfd.

---

**Remark** As tessellation pointed out: "To get a global almost complex structure the only obstruction is the gluing condition which is a purely algebraic topological obstruction."

The idea however is to define almost complex structure in some **natural manner** to skip the middle part in below diagram

$$\text{geometric structure}\implies\text{algebraic topological obstructions vanish}\implies \text{there is an almost complex structure}$$

Comment: Well, almost complex structures are well known geometric structures that lead naturally to almost complex structures - if $M$ admits an almost complex structure $J$, every bundle automorphism $\varphi$ gives rise to another almost complex structure $J_{\varphi}$.

Comment: It should be noted that your formula does not yield an almost complex structure for most choices of $\omega$ and $g$ -- the compatibility condition $J^2 = -\operatorname{Id}$ is an additional requirement that must be imposed. For any given symplectic form, there are many compatible choices of $g$, but not every $g$ works.

Comment: @JackLee You are right. I edited the question to make it compatible, but I stated it without referring to $J,$ due to the reason it would cause circular reasoning then.

Comment: Just a comment: An even dimensional manifold is always admits locally almost complex structure. To get a global almost complex structure the only obstruction is the gluing condition which is a purely algebraic topological obstruction. It is  basically the reduction of the structure group from real to complex matrix group.

Comment: @tessellation I know that "An even dimensional manifold is always admits locally almost complex structure". This is why I wrote " I am interested, if there are any well known geometric structures on manifold that lead in some **natural manner** to almost complex structure". I would say that we have the following
$$\text{geometric structure}\implies\text{algebraic topological obstructions vanish}\implies \text{there is an almost complex structure}$$
I want to find geometric structure to avoid middle part. I.e. define $J$ is some **natural manner**.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a kind of answer you are looking for, but it might be useful... My answer has to do with twistor theory. If $X$ is an oriented $4$-manifold with a conformal structure $c$, Define the bundle $Z$ of all $J_x$, endomorphism of $T_x(X)$ such that $J_x^2 = -Id$,and $J_x$ is compatible with the orientation of $X$, as $x$ varies over $X$. Then $Z$ is an $S^2$ bundle over $X$, and has a natural almost complex structure on it. See for instance the famous paper by Atiyah, Hitchin and Singer. That being said, I am not sure if this is a kind of answer you are looking for.